# Problema con insercion multiple SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una insercion multiple en SQL server de la siguiente manera:

```
insert into Registros (idi,cant,fecha,usu,obs,lot,ven) 
values 
(2,'1/100','2020/01/20 16:44:59','asd','asd','999','2020-01-03')
```

Esta es mi tabla:

```
create table Registros(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,
idi int not null,
cant varchar(5) not null,
fecha DATETIME,
usu VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
obs varchar(50),
lot varchar (50),
efectuado varchar(20),
ven date,
);
```

Pasa que esta estructura me funciona sin mayores problemas al momento de insertar pocos registros, pero al intentar de insertar 100 registros me envia el siguiente error :

```
      insert into Registros (idi,cant,fecha,usu,obs,lot,ven) 
    values 
    (2,'1/100','2020/01/20 16:44:59','asd','asd','999','2020-01-03'),
    (2,'2/100','2020/01/20 16:44:59','asd','asd','999','2020-01-03'),
     ..........
    (2,'99/100','2020/01/20 16:44:59','asd','asd','999','2020-01-03'),
    (2,'100/100','2020/01/20 16:44:59','asd','asd','999','2020-01-03')

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Buscando el error, corresponde a cuando se insertan mas variables de las permitidas por la tabla, por ejemplo si tengo un varchar(10) e inserto 20 caracteres. Pero este no es el problema ya que como menciono anteriormente si inserto menor cantidad de registros no tiene problemas.

¿Existe alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Comment: qué tipo de dato es la columna `valores`?

Comment: ¿Realmente es así `Insert into *tabla* (valores)` la sentencia de inserción? ¿No debiera ser en todo caso algo así `Insert into *tabla* (col1, col2, col3)`? Adhiero al pedido de Lamak.

Comment: he editado la pregunta, espero se entienda un poco mejor.

Comment: necesitamos saber el tipo de datos de cada columna igualmente

Comment: No es un problema de los 100 valores, porque `VALUES` tiene un límite de 1.000

Comment: Ahora si he entregado todos los valores de mi tabla.

Comment: bueno, acá se ve lo importante de poner los detalles correctos en la pregunta. El error claramente se ve en los dos últimos registros que estás cargando, ya que tienen más de 5 caracteres para el campo `cantidad` (`99/100` y `100/100`). Este error lo vas a tener desde el décimo registro, de hecho (`10/100`)

Comment: ooooh, muchas gracias y perdon por la molestia :D. Estuve mucho rato buscándole respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que desde el registro diez en adelante intenta hacer un insert de la cadena '10/100' que posee 6 caracteres en un campo varchar(5) y por eso devuelve el error "String or binary data would be truncated."

Te recomiendo que amplies la cantidad de caracteres que admite el campo **cant** de tu tabla, a un varchar (10) por ejemplo.

```
ALTER TABLE Registros ALTER COLUMN cant VARCHAR (10);
```

Luego intentá hacer el insert nuevamente, tené en cuenta modificar este campo también en las tablas relacionadas.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bien, para poder completar tu sentencia "INSERT" debes tener en cuenta varias cosas:

1. El número de columnas a insertar debe coincidir con las columnas indicadas.
2. Validar columna por columna el tipo de dato destino así como los origenes que intentas insertar.
3. Validar que el dato que intentas insertar coincida con el tamaño de la columna.
4. Si intentas insertar datos alfanuméricos, debes escapar las comillas simples y/o caracteres que puedan afectar la sintaxis de tu consulta.
5. Con 100 registros no creo que tengas problema de insertar datos masivamente, regularmente eso sucede cuando se insertan mas de 1000 registros que comunmente mayor a 1000 registros es recomendable hacerlo a través de un proceso batch.

Recomendaciones:

Si un campo de tu tabla tiene como máximo 10 caracteres permitidos y el dato que intentas insertar tiene mas de 10, puedes truncarlo a 10 de la siguiente forma:

`SUBSTRING('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 1, 10);`

siendo el dato 123456789 tu dato de entrada, indicando que iniciará desde el primer caracter hasta el número 10.

Tu problema que nos explicas es muy general, no contiene más detalles de lo que realmente estas haciendo. Si necesitas más información, favor de indicar más detalles del mismo.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con los campos exactos de mi tabla. el problema es que no puedo insertar los 100 registros.

Comment: He copiado la estructura de tu tabla así como el primer dato a insertar que es:(2,'1/100','2020/01/20 16:44:59','asd','asd','999','2020-01-03') y me lo inserto sin problema, lo copie mas de 100 veces y los inserto sin problemas. Opino que quizá alguno de esos 100 registros que intentas insertar tiene algun dato mal.